# How do I show that YZ and Y+Z are dependent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

**Question**

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be two independent random variables that take value $1$ with probability $\frac12$ and value $-1$ with probability $\frac12$. Show that $X=YZ$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$ but is not independent of $W=Y+Z$.

**Attempt**

Random variables are independent if $P(X=x, Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y)$. Therefore I need to show that this equation does not hold for $X$ and $W$. I can calculate the probability that $X$ or $W$ takes a particular value. What I don't understand is how I can calculate the joint probability $P(W=w, X=x)$.

Could I please get feedback on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we find the distribution of $X$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=1) &= \mathbb P(Y=1,Z=1)+\mathbb P(Y=-1,Z=-1) = \left(\frac12\right)^2 + \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac12\\
\mathbb P(X=-1) &= \mathbb P(Y=1,Z=-1)+\mathbb P(Y=-1,Z=1) = \left(\frac12\right)^2 + \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac12.
\end{align}
and of $W$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(W=2) &= \mathbb P(Y=1,Z=1) = \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac14\\
\mathbb P(W=0) &= \mathbb P(Y=1,Z=-1) + \mathbb P(Y=-1,Z=1) = \left(\frac12\right)^2+\left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac12\\
\mathbb P(W=-2) &= \mathbb P(Y=-1,Z=-1) = \left(\frac12\right)^2 = \frac14.
\end{align}

Next, we compute the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ and see that these random variables are indeed independent:

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=1,Y=1) &= \mathbb P(Z=1,Y=1) = \frac14 = \mathbb P(X=1)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=1)\\
\mathbb P(X=-1,Y=1) &= \mathbb P(Z=-1,Y=1) = \frac14 = \mathbb P(X=-1)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=1)\\
\mathbb P(X=1,Y=-1) &= \mathbb P(Z=-1,Y=-1) = \frac14 = \mathbb P(X=1)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=-1)\\
\mathbb P(X=-1,Y=-1) &= \mathbb P(Z=1,Y=-1) = \frac14 = \mathbb P(X=-1)\cdot\mathbb P(Y=-1)
\end{align}
(by a very similar argument we see that $X$ and $Z$ are independent).
Finally, we note that $X$ and $W$ are not independent, as
$$
\mathbb P(X=-1,W=2) = 0 \ne \frac18 = \mathbb P(X=-1)\cdot\mathbb P(W=2).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Any of the events you need to calculate the probability of is composed of some of the elementary events listed in the following table.  You can therefore calculate the probability of any such event by summing the probabilities of those of which it is composed.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Y&Z&X&W&\text{Probability}\\
\hline
-1&-1&1&-2&\frac{1}{4}\\
-1&1&-1&0&\frac{1}{4}\\
1&-1&-1&0&\frac{1}{4}\\
1&1&1&2&\frac{1}{4}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 0):

All you need to demonstrate that $X$ is not independent of $W$ is to note that $P(X=1)=\frac12$ but

$$P(X=1|W=0)=0\neq P(X=1)$$

In words, "the probability that $X=1$ given that $W=0$ is zero", since if $W=0$ then either $Y=1$ and $Z=-1$ or $Y=-1$ and $Z=1$, and either way $X=-1$.